# pycharm track 'print' output in debug mode

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I am new to python and pycharm. 
I am writing a program that takes years to run, so I want to see the iteration number while debugging.

this is my code:

```
import urllib2
for i in range(n):
    print i        
    responses[i]=u2.urlopen(urls[i])
```

(I have an array of n urls)

so, when I run it I see the outputs:

```
0
1
2
3
etc
```

but when I am debugging I don't see the output.

any idea anyone?

Comment: Are you trying to say that debugger _did_ reach "print i" & still didn't print it?

Comment: yes - I can't understand why...

Comment: it is a bug, restart/update your pycharm happened a lot to me

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple code block and there should not be any problem with Pycharm debugger. I suggest to use latest PyCharm version 5.0. 
Right click on your python file and select 'Debug yourPythonFile.py'.It should print value of i.
Just a small suggestion, use `(responses.append(u2.urlopen(urls[i]))` instead of `responses[i]=u2.urlopen(urls[i])`